# Build comma seperated string from the struct in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following struct in C# class

```
public struct Employee
        {
            public const string EMPID = "EMP_ID";
            public const string FName = "FIRST_NAME";
            public const string LNAME = "LAST_NAME";
            public const string DEPTID = "DEPT_ID";

        }
```

Is there an easy way to build a string as follows

```
const string mainquery="INSERT INTO EMP(EMP_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,DEPT_ID) VALUES(:EMP_ID,:FIRST_NAME,:LAST_NAME,:DEPT_ID)"
```

Instead of doing as follows
and then concatenating it.

```
const string EMP_COLS=
                EMPLOYEE.EMPID + "," +
                EMPLOYEE.FNAME + "," +
        EMPLOYEE.LNAME + "," +
                EMPLOYEE.DEPTID;

            const string EMP_Values=
                EMPLOYEE.EMPID + ":" +
                EMPLOYEE.FNAME + ":" +
        EMPLOYEE.LNAME + ":" +
                EMPLOYEE.DEPTID;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
var fields = typeof(Employee).GetFields();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
{
    sb.Append(fields[i].GetValue(new Employee()));
    if (i < fields.Length - 1)
    {
        sb.Append(',');
    }
}

string result = sb.ToString();
// The above will be "EMP_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,DEPT_ID"
```

*Edit*: Note that above I'm assuming you've got `using` directives for both `System.Reflection` and `System.Text`.

Comment: But will that guarantee that the order is consistent?  It would be bad if for some reason the outuputted order changed and data was inserted into the wrong columns.

Comment: That's an excellent point Walter--there isn't any guarantee.  That said, I believe there's an *implicit* "guarantee" that the order is as-defined order in the struct.  Not a place to be rolling the dice though, to your point.

Comment: You should never depend on the order, but considering the result wanted (as seen in the mainquery declared above) I don't think the order would matter anyway, you'll just get it out once and then use the same list in both parts of the mainquery...

Answer (score 1):

If the struct held readonly properties rather than public consts you could do it with Reflection. You could call `Type.GetProperties`, loop through them all and call them to get out the values and insert the values into a `List<string>` and then join them with `string.Join(", ", myList);` or something.
You'd then get the first part of the string as `EMP_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DEPT_ID` and you'd need to make a copy of that and add the `:`s as needed and you'd have both parts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `string.Format(string format, object[] arg)` Method as follows:

```
string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO EMP({0},{1},{2},{3}) VALUES(:{0},:{1},:{2},:{3})",
                Employee.EMPID,
                Employee.FNAME,
                Employee.LNAME,
                Employee.DEPTID);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of mapping dictionary, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030856/separating-columnname-and-value-in-c/3031086#3031086), or you could just use some ORM  tool to do the mapping for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] values = new[] {
            "EMP_ID",
            "FIRST_NAME",
            "LAST_NAME",
            "DEPT_ID",
        };

        var columns = string.Join(",", values);
        var parameters = ":" + string.Join(",:", values);

        var sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO EMP({0}) VALUES({1})",
            columns,
            parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] cols = typeof(Employee).GetFields()
                 .Select(f => f.GetValue(null).ToString()).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
      "INSERT INTO EMP({0}) VALUES(:{1})", 
      string.Join(",", cols), 
      string.Join(",:", cols)));
```